# Unable to compile (build) code with MPLAB for PIC with CCS C compiler

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab, pic-ccs

I'm a newbie  trying to lean PIC, i downloaded MPLAB and MPLAB X ide . 
Ihave done this around 100 times and looked over web enough before asking this question, but my code is not compiled  and it is failed always.
Here is what i did:-

1. Created a  new project using **PROJECT WIZARD**
2. Edited the code
3. Copied the  "16F871.H" library in both folder (i created the project in) and added it to the header files in MPLAB IDE.

Here's my code

```
*> // IFIN.C Tests an input
#include " 16F877A.h "
void main()
{
int x; // Declare variable
output_D(0); // Clear all outputs
while(1) //
{
x = input(PIN_C0); // Get input state
if(x = = 1)output_high(PIN_D0); // Change output
}
}*
```

> But on compiling the code  i'm getting error a this  Executing:
>
> "C:\Program Files\PICC\Ccsc.exe" +FM "NEW.c" #_*DEBUG=1 +ICD +DF +LN
>   +T +A +M +Z +Y=9 +EA  #*_16F877A=TRUE
>
> *** Error 18 "NEW.c" Line 2(10,23): File can not be opened
>
> ```
> Not in project "C:\Users\jatin\Desktop\DHAKKAN PIC\ 16F877A.h "
>
> Not in "C:\Program Files\PICC\devices\ 16F877A.h "
>
> Not in "C:\Program Files\PICC\drivers\ 16F877A.h "
> ```
>
> *** Error 128 "NEW.c" Line 2(10,17): A #DEVICE required before this line
>
> *** Error 12 "NEW.c" Line 6(9,10): Undefined identifier  -- output_D
>
> *** Error 12 "NEW.c" Line 9(10,11): Undefined identifier  -- input
>
> *** Error 51 "NEW.c" Line 10(8,9): A numeric expression must appear here
>
> ```
>   5 Errors,  0 Warnings. Build Failed. Halting build on first failure as requested. BUILD FAILED: Mon Jul 08 15:09:17 2013
> ```

I would be grateful to you if you could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most immediate problem I can see is the following line of code:

```
#include " 16F877A.h "
```

You should remove the spaces because it's trying to open a file that contains spaces which is why you're getting multiple errors related to that file. While in general extra whitespace doesn't matter a lot in C / C++ code for any literals enclosed in quotes it certainly does.

Another area where you shouldn't insert extra spaces is also between operators such as `==` so the space between those two characters should be removed from line 10 as well so it should look like this:

```
if(x == 1) output_high(PIN_D0); // Change output
```